# Highlighted undo in Vim

Tags: highlight, undo-redo

I'm trying to have a highlighted undo in Vim, like spacemacs default config.
Sometimes when I want quick undo's, I can't realize what changed because it's instantaneous. So I am trying to have something like this when a press undo:

[image: highlighted undo]

Anyone have an idea how to do this in Vim?

(I already have Gundo plugin, i just want to make the default undo more smooth)

**Edit**: The [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) plugin does the work ([Gundo](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim) doesn't highlight the changes), just use the `UndotreeToggle` command and all future changes on the file will be highlighted.

Comment: Nice idea. You can create a highlight with `matchadd()`, but slightly more tricky is working out which parts of the file have changed.

Comment: Perhaps saving to a temporary buffer/file before the undo, then to a 2nd buffer/file after the undo, and highlighting the new diffs after cleaning (or changing the color of) the previous ones. Could get slow for large files.

Comment: [UndoTree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) does actually highlight changed *lines*, but it doesn't do it in realtime. I think it uses GNU diff. Getting word granularity would be an [extra step](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/jsh/blob/master/code/shellscript/diffing/worddiff.sh) (e.g. split lines at [word breaks](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/jsh/blob/master/code/shellscript/stream/escapenewlines.sh), diff, recombine lines).

Comment: These plugins come close, but they are still line-based: [smeargle](https://github.com/FriedSock/smeargle) can highlight lines changed since the last save. [changesPlugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/changesPlugin) marks changed lines (including deletions) in the gutter on the left.

Comment: @joeytwiddle, changesPlugin can also highlight the last change region

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## New solution

You can view your last changes with the `:changes` command. So you can fecth your most recent line change with a regex and then apply the line to `matchadd()` as suggested by @joeytwiddle.

Here is the code :

```
function! DiffWithPrevious()
  call clearmatches()
  redir => message
  silent changes
  redir END
  let line = matchstr(message, '\v\n\s{4}1[^0-9]*\zs\d+\ze')
  highlight TemporalDiff ctermbg=green guibg=green
  let m = matchadd('TemporalDiff', '\%'.line.'l')
endfunction
```

**Note** :

- <s>This function only add a new highlight without removing the old one, so you'd have to remove the old one first.</s> With the `clearmatches` function you can remove the matches before adding a new one. Careful, it will remove **ALL** matches. If you want more granularity, you can save your match and remove it manually :

e.g.

```
function! DiffWithPrevious()
  call matchdelete(m)
  ... 
  let m = matchadd('TemporalDiff', '\%'.line.'l')
endfunction
```

- After some tests, I found out it only works for one-line change.

References :

- [Why is \r a newline for Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73438/2558252)
- [regex in vimscript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3135448/2558252)
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_long_lines

---

## Old solution

Here is a possible solution, mainly inspired by [Diff current buffer and the original file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Diff_current_buffer_and_the_original_file) :

```
function! DiffWithPrevious()
  undo
  write
  redo
  let filetype=&ft
  diffthis
  vnew | r # | normal! 1Gdd
  diffthis
  exe "setlocal bt=nofile bh=wipe nobl noswf ro ft=" . filetype
endfunction
```

The idea is to diff the file with the file on the system, so you undo your last change, write it, redo the las change and execute the diff.

I think this should do the job for time-to-time temporal diff visualisations.

Comment: there is a way to clear the message "buffer" on DiffWithPrevious() ? I wish the function highlighted just the last changes,but highlight is accumulating over time, im trying something like message = 0 or message = ""  but no sucess.

Comment: Of course yeah, let me update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check my [changes plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/changesPlugin) and be sure to set the variable `g:changes_linehi_diff` to 1

Answer (score 2):

For someone who is trying the same of me, that is closest that i reached thanks to the answers.

```
function! DiffWithPrevious()
  call clearmatches()
  undo
  redir => message
  silent changes
  redir END
  let line = matchstr(message, '\v\n\s{4}1[^0-9]*\zs\d+\ze')
  highlight TemporalDiff ctermbg=black guibg=black
  let m = matchadd('TemporalDiff', '\%'.line.'l')
  redraw
  let gchar = getchar()
  highlight TemporalDiff ctermbg=none guibg=none
  let m = matchadd('TemporalDiff', '\%'.line.'l')
endfunction
```